# Firefox issue with div's as table cell

Tags: css, firefox, css-tables, font-awesome-4

I am trying to create a transparent overlay on a background image with a Fontawesome chevron, as shown in the design comp below.

[image]

After trying all sorts of things to get three floated `DIV`s to look like this, I resorted to using

`display:table-cell`

for the divs to the left and right with the white background, and the keep the DIV with the chevron in the middle a block.

This works fine in IE and Chrome, but Firefox pushes the `DIV` in the center down for some reason. This is a problem in the final version with the transparent image because I need to keep this `DIV` exactly 160 pixels wide. `Width` and `Max-width` don't seem to work with `display: table-cell`.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G4EXL/15/).

Question 1: How can I get this work in FF?
Question 2: Is there a better way (short of using a single image with the round cutout wide enough to account for 4K monitors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get it to work in FF, you simply need to add `vertical-align: top` to the `.whitebox` element. Since it is a `table-cell` element, it will respect the `vertical-align` property and align itself as you would expect.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zA797/)

```
.jumbotaboverlay .whitebox {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

In regards to your other question, it is completely dependent on what browsers you are trying to support.